# How do I reference a variable inside a ssm in Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-ssm

Recently I updated a serverless environment from an extremely outdated version to the latest and have run into many issues. one of which I don't seem to understand why it isn't working. Previously we reference AWS parameter store variable with ssm references like so:

```
SQS_URL: ${ssm:/foo/${opt:env}/sqsUrl}
```

Now I have updated our use of the `opt` to make use of `env` so it looks like:

```
SQS_URL: ${ssm:/foo/${env:ENV, "NOT_VALID"}/sqsUrl}
```

But I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve variable at "provider.environment.SQS_URL": Value not found at "ssm" source,

We used to make extensive use all over the place of this to set environment variables on lambdas so that we could pass values to them for them to use at run time, but serverless doesn't seem to like this anymore but looking at [the documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#nesting-variable-references) it seems like it should work. Can anyone help me resolve this please?

Thank you!

Comment: Somewhat hesitant interacting with the NSA, at the risk of asking the obvious, hardcoding the SSM path works and the env:ENV exist.  What is the SSM variable supposed to be or diff between this "provider.environment.SQS_QUEUE_URL" the value display in the error message.

Comment: The SQS_QUEUE_URL was a sloppy and paste error on my part, basically all of the ssm variables that we passed this way are broken now, and there are two very similarly named ones and I copied the error for the wrong one, I have edited it to fix this. Hard coding does work, but I wanted to be able to just use the environment to switch which parameters are referenced, if I didn't do that what would be the canonical way to do that? e.g. if I have a ${ssm:/foo/production/bar} and ${ssm:/foo/test/bar} how would I get my deployment to ref the correct one?

Comment: Understood, was just trying to understand or narrow down where the error was coming from. SQS_URL: ${ssm:/foo/${opt:env}/sqsUrl} this was working in previous version meaning ${opt:env} was replaced with  "/foo/production/bar" or "/foo/test/bar" depending on the environment variable settings.

Comment: The serverless-dotenv-plugin is directly impacted by v3. Indeed, for technical reasons the plugin will no longer be able to resolve ${env:xxx} variables from .env files.
However, .env files are now natively supported by Serverless Framework v3. Set useDotenv: true to use .env variables with ${env:xxx}:    (scroll down the page) 
 https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/upgrading-v3

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `SQS_URL` variable. Error message says it can't find `SQS_QUEUE_URL`.

If it's still working after fixing variable names. Try with a given environment to narrow it down.

```
SQS_URL: ${ssm:/foo/DEV/sqsUrl}
```

Comment: Before I posted the question I had tried with a fixed path, e.g. ${ssm:/foo/test/sqsUrl} and that works but I want to be able to deploy to multiple environments without having to have different deployment scripts for each, so without that substitution what would be the canonical way to do this in serverless?

Comment: If it's working when you specify the environment. That means you either do not set ENV variable in your serverless.yml or you have not created sqsUrl parameter in the ENV you are trying.

Comment: @NSA Have you sorted the issue?

Comment: CharithJ I resolved my issue, with a hack by creating two versions of my serverless.yml files one for test and one for production that I then copy to "serverless.yml" when I go to deploy and that allows me to remove the embedded variable references inside the ssm references, which formerly worked but now do not. This new way allows me to hard code them to the two paths that I needed. Its sub-optimal but it allowed me to moved past my need to deploy.